# await axiosが終了しない

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

## 説明

dbに情報を登録するapi`api/product`を実装し

> await axios.post('api/product', ...)

という形でapiを呼び出したのですが、いつまで経っても`axios.post`が終了せず

> console.log(res.status)

が呼び出されません。
このようなことが起こる理由が理解できません。

なお、dbへのデータの登録は正常に完了しています。

## コード

```js
import axios from 'axios'

async regist_product(): Promise<void> {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/product', {
        id,
        original_id: this.product_original_id,
        name: this.product_name,
        price: this.product_price
      })
      console.log(res.status)
    }
```

Comment: API（`api/product`）からレスポンスを返していますか？返していない場合、axios.postはサーバーからのレスポンスを待っている状態になります。

Comment: @himenon apiの実装を確認するとres.status(200)と書かれていたので、.end()を追加するとawait axiosが期待通り終了しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

api側の実装のレスポンスの設定が不適切だったことが原因。

## 修正前

```js
res.status(201)
```

## 修正後

```js
res.status(201).end()
```